# How to interpret divided powers in Kostant Z Form when passing to a field of characteristic p > 0?

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G = GL_n(\mathbb{K})$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field of characteristic $p > 0$. Let $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Let $e_{ij}$ denote the elementary matrices which are a basis for $\mathfrak{g}$. The Kostant $\mathbb{Z}$ form is the $\mathbb{Z}$-subalgebra $U_\mathbb{Z}$ of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ generated by elements $e_{ij}^r/r!$ for $1 \leq i \neq j \leq n$, $r \geq 0$ and ${h_i \choose r}$ for  $1 \leq i \leq n$, $r \geq 0$ and $h_i = e_{ii}$. This is a free $\mathbb{Z}$ module with $\mathbb{Z}$-basis given by monomials of the form:

$\prod e_{ij}^{a_{ij}}/a_{ij}! \prod {h_i \choose r_i}$

with $a_{ij}, r_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, product taken in any fixed order. Finally, let $U_\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{K} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{U}_\mathbb{Z}$. It can be shown that this is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Dist}(G)$.

My question is how does one interpret these denominators, especially since for $r \geq p$ it looks like we are dividing by zero?  For instance, is the following computation valid? Let us identify $1 \otimes x$ with $x$, and let $ p = 3$.

$e_{45}e_{14}^2/2! - e_{14}^2/2!e_{45} = 1/2! ([e_{45},e_{14}]e_{14} + e_{14}[e_{45}, e_{14}]) = 1/2!(-2e_{15}) = -e_{15}$

Comment: I think the answer is the most naïve possible:  you *don't* interpret them.  That is, the whole point is that the elements $e_{i j}^r$ themselves don't exist, or at least are $0$ (unless $r < p$), but only the divided power, which should be thought of as a formal symbol, albeit denoted by a very suggestive notation.  Any equality that can be performed in the $\mathbb Z$-form remains valid in any specialisation.

Comment: I think they are "correct" (i.e better behaved) analogous of $e_{ij}$ in positive characteristic. For example, $d_p := (\partial/ \partial x)^p$ is always zero in positive characteristic, so a better analogous of this differential operator is $d' := d_p/p!$.